# Time span between dates in specific format

Tags: javascript, date, date-format, date-comparison

I'm, trying to do some date comparison in javascript but I don't find any way where the outcome is what I need.

I wanna compare two dates in `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format, and have the outcome outputted in amount of time between those two dates.

example, if I input `2015-03-26 05:00:00` and `2015-03-29 05:00:00`, I want it to output `- 0000-00-03 00:00:00`, if i were to switch positions I would get an positive number etc.

The thing is I only manage to compare dates in the standard getDate() format, I can parse my values to this format and get the millisecond span between the dates with:

```
var parsedDate = Date.parse("2015-03-26 05:00:00");
var formattedDate = new Date(parsedDate);
var today = new Date();
var MS = new Date(Math.abs(today - formattedDate));
```

But I can't get those ms back to my format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`, I'm quite new with javascript, maybe my lack of knowledge forces me to go the wrong way, any tips is apreciated.

Comment: "want to", not "wanna"

Comment: you can't reparse them in the way you are trying to do if you are looking to transform it to datetime format 0000-00-03 00:00:00 cause unix timestamp begins in 00:00:00 1 January 1970 UTC unless you are looking to make it in the string type

Comment: Converting the end result to a string type is not a problem, how would I manage that?